# How can I set "Update Frames" to None in XCode 8.3?

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

I'm doing a the Ray Wanderlich iOS Appprentice and we are right now working with AutoLayout.

I'm asked to add some constraints to the this particular Table View and I can do so.

What I can't do is modify the "Update Frames" behavior. In this particular case, the book asks me to set it to None.

[image: Image of missing menu]

I can tell you that his is not the default behavior because my label has shrunk as per the warning in the book—see attached warning and image.

> Note: If you had set Update Frames to “Items of New Constraints”, then Interface Builder would have moved the label to where the dotted
>   box is. That’s why you left it set to None because you didn’t want it
>   to do that here.

[image: Wrong Reaction to the View]

What can I do to do as the tutorial intends?

[image: My XCode without the option]

Answer (score -1):

So either you click on the round arrow:

[image: update frames buttom]

or by simply using this shortkey:

[image: shortkey update frames]